# Windows kernel Dev

Tags: windows, c++, kernel-mode

I'm writing a basic program that'd allow me to list the running processes on a windows system but by simply trying to go through the ActiveProcessLinks of the _EPROCESS structure.The problem I'm facing right now is that I can't access directly the elements of the pointer to EPROCESS structure as it's considered as incomplete pointer. Below is the snippet of the section I'm having trouble with:

````
#include <wdm.h>

#define MAX_PATH 260
VOID listprocess() {

    // Access the doubly linked list of processes
    PEPROCESS currentProcess = PsGetCurrentProcess();
    PLIST_ENTRY processListEntry = currentProcess->ActiveProcessLinks.Flink;```


PS: I'm a beginner so please indulge me if it's too basic as question, Thanks!!!
````

Comment: `EPROCESS` is considered - from a programming point of view - an opaque structure (you may know it exist, but you're not supposed to deal with it). Main reason is that the structure happens to change a lot. Best way to use it is to extract and convert it from the PDB file of the **exact** kernel version you're experimenting with into C and use the header in your program. There are some programs to convert PDB structures (named `UDT` in PDB parlance) to C header files (e.g. [pdbex](https://github.com/wbenny/pdbex)) or online websites such as [Vergilius](https://www.vergiliusproject.com/).

Comment: I'll try to look into that, thanks!!!